# How to submit form with filled Entity object instead of Request object?

Tags: php, symfony, validation, entity, symfony-forms

I want to use Symfony Form just for validation purpose. So I fill entity with data:

```
    $reductionCalculator = new ReductionCalculator();
    $reductionCalculator->setClaim($claim);
    $reductionCalculator->setDecreasedCapital($decreasedCapital);
    $reductionCalculator->setCredit($credit);
```

then creating form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ReductionCalculatorType::class);
```

and I trying submit data:

```
$form->submit($reductionCalculator);
//or
// $form->setData($reductionCalculator);
```

and validate:

```
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    $this->throwApiProblemValidationException($form);
}
```

But this throw Exception:

> "Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\ReductionCalculator as
>   array"

How to do this correct without changing the object to array. Maybe other Form method than `submit()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need it for validation why dont you just skip the form and use the validation component directly?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: Thanks. (because I'm watching tutorial about symfony 2.6)